# How to interpret the sampling weight of each observation in the dataset?

Tags: sampling, survey, weights

I have a data set containing a sampling weight for each observation.
Here are the top observations from the data set :

[image]

My question is what does this sampling (survey) weight means?
How to interpret it ? What does it tell about the observation case it is associated with?

this [link](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/10/02/weight-variables-in-statistics-sas.html) says that The sum of the survey weights equals the population size,  is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

The sum of weights *can* be the population size. In that case the individual weight stands for the number of people in the population that that observation represents. The sum of weights can also be the sample size. In that case the individual weight stands for the number of times that that observation should have appeared if the sample was a simple random sample from the population.

In my field the latter scaling of weights is more common.

Comment: thanks for the response. It helpled me a lot but I still have one more question. so if you want to find out the number of people with a particular observation, how will you do so by using the second scaling approach('In my field the latter scaling of weights is more common')

Comment: Weight * number of people in population / number of people in sample